# Cloud service for windows phone 7 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure

In feb 2013 the windows azure toolkit for windows phone 7 apps has been suspended as per the [link](http://watwp.codeplex.com/)

Are there any cloud services that i can use instead of this azure on windows phone 7 apps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not suspended, but superseded. What this means is that now you can use [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) since it is specifically designed to work with application for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store.

As you would with the "big house" Azure, you can use AMS through a SDK:

- [Windows Phone 8/Windows Store](https://go.microsoft.com/fwLink/p/?LinkID=268375)
- [Windows Phone 7.5](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/0.3.3-rc)
  (pre-release)

Or you could access it through the standard [REST layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710108.aspx).